# google safe browsing 4.0 API returns 400 status

Tags: php, http-status-code-400, safe-browsing

I'm all set up with an API key and have written PHP server-side code to fetch Google Safe Browsing [GSB] status based on a URL. Version 4 of GSB lookup API is described here -> https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api#http-post-request . I'm using PHP-cURL library and PHP 7 from command line on my server as a test. The POST contents I'm sending are right from the example on the Google developers site, though I've cut it to only one URL and removed periods from the version number and the URL (yes, I know the URL would fail) because they seem to generate their own odd errors:

```
{"client":{"clientId":"yourcompanyname","clientVersion":"152"},"threatInfo":{"threatTypes":["MALWARE","SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],"platformTypes":["WINDOWS","threatEntryTypes":["URL"],"threatEntries":[{"url":"wwwurltocheck1org/"}]}}
```

I get a 400 HTTP status return fro php-curl and this error:

```
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"client\":{\"clientId\":\"yourcompanyname\",\"clientVersion\":\"152\"},\"threatInfo\":{\"threatTypes\":[\"MALWARE\",\"SOCIAL_ENGINEERING\"],\"platformTypes\":[\"WINDOWS\",\"threatEntryTypes\":[\"URL\"],\"threatEntries\":[{\"url\":\"wwwurltocheck1org/\"}]}}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"client\":{\"clientId\":\"yourcompanyname\",\"clientVersion\":\"152\"},\"threatInfo\":{\"threatTypes\":[\"MALWARE\",\"SOCIAL_ENGINEERING\"],\"platformTypes\":[\"WINDOWS\",\"threatEntryTypes\":[\"URL\"],\"threatEntries\":[{\"url\":\"wwwurltocheck1org/\"}]}}' could not be found in request message.",
```

I will point out that it's saying "Unknown name" and then quoting my entire POST contents as if the entire POST contents are being interpreted as a single "name". But then it says "Cannot bind query parameter" and quotes (again) the whold POST contents as if it thought it was a single field. What's a "field" in this context? This has me stumped.

Yes, I am adding the application/json header:

```
[Content-Type] => application/json
```

Hitting the GSB API at:

```
[url] => https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=MY_KEY
```

And php-curl tells me it received JSON back from the GSB service:

```
[content_type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Does anyone know what those messages mean? "Invalid JSON payload..." and "Cannot bind query parameter." - I can't relate to them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your error response with the extra "\" in there, you are encoding your json string when you dont need to.

i.e if you have `$json = '{"key":"value"}';` as your json it looks like you are also applying `json_encode($json);` to that string. You dont need to do that - you can just use the string without the encoding, as its already in the correct format to be processed. I hope that is what it was and is helpful!

Comment: Yes, that was it. I correct my code to just let PHP convert an array into a string, and it was correctly handled. I had a json_encode() that I didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in your JSON, `platformTypes` doesn't have a close square bracket.

You had 
`"platformTypes":["WINDOWS","threatEntryTypes":....`
There should be a ']'  after `"WINDOWS"`.